CURL, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION and Workerman
I have a strange problem with a CURL callback function and websocket connection by Workerman.
For some reason, the a$connection->send function doesn't send chunks of data, but waits for all from CURL. Echo function correctly outputs a data line by line to the console.
My code:
use Workerman\Worker;
    
$ws_worker            = new Worker("websocket://domain.com:2020");
$ws_worker->transport = 'ssl'; 
$ws_worker->onConnect = function($connections) {
    echo "New connection\n";
};
    
$ws_worker->onMessage = function($connection, $data) {
        
        $ch = curl_init();      
        
        $write_function = function $callback ($ch, $r) use ($connection) {
            
            if (!empty($r)) {
                echo $r;                  // Correct output line by line to the console
                $connection->send($r);    // !!! Here is a problem, waits for full data then sends all
            }
            
            return strlen($data);
        }; 
        
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "sample url");        
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION,  $write_function); 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'some data');
        $headers    = [];
        $headers[]  = 'Content-Type: application/json';
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        if (curl_errno($ch)) {
            echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
        }
            
        curl_close($ch);
    };

Where is the problem?
